# babel doesn't resolve path aliases

Tags: node.js, babeljs

My babel doesn't resolve path aliases.
I have following file structure:

```
app  
--helpers.js  
controllers  
--index.js  
routes  
--index.js  
app.js  
babel.config.js
```

app.js imports routes/index.js that imports controllers/index.js and in controllers/index.js I am importing like

```
import { some_func } from "@app/helpers.js";
```

and it doesn't work

my babel config:

```
export default {  
    plugins: [  
        ["module-resolver", {  
            "root": ["./"],  
            "alias": {  
                "@app": "./app",
                "@": "./"
            }
        }]
    ]
}
```

my dev dependencies:

```
"@babel/cli": "^7.21.0",  
"@babel/core": "^7.21.4",  
"@babel/node": "^7.20.7",  
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.21.4",  
"@babel/register": "^7.21.0",  
"babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0"
```

running with command

```
nodemon --exec babel-node --require @babel/register app.js
```

error detail:

```
node:internal/errors:490  
ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);  


Error \[ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND\]: Cannot find package '@app/helpers.js' imported from /path/to/project/controllers/index.js
```

Where am I wrong or what might I do?

I searched some forums but nothing helps me